# Can I shuffle data for delivery duration estimate problem?

Tags: machine-learning, shuffle, forecast

I'm trying to write a solution to a food delivery duration time problem (so called lead time). I used algorithms such as random forest and gradient boosting which gave OK results but not amazing. I have daily data covering 3 years, that I split to train/test with an 80/20% split.

To try and improve results, I repeated the split however I did it randomly, i.e. on a shuffled data. My model, does not use any relations between data points, it only predicts the lead time using that specific sample's features (e.g. type of food, who's the carrier, expected delivery duration, etc.)
When I do this, the results improve dramatically, which makes me question I'm doing something illegal.

I wanted to know if I can actually shuffle the data? Can I do that?

Comment: Show your code. [ask] and [mre]

Comment: Welcome to SO; for such non-programming ML questions, please see the intro and NOTE in https://stackoverflow.com/tags/machine-learning/info

Answer (score 0):

It's kind of difficult to help u because your initial situation is unclear. But it sounds like during your repeated split u shuffle train and test data - that would explain the sudden improvements. For a reproducible result u should also consider using a random seed.